# wamp server and android misconnection

Tags: php, android, wamp

I have a simple login and register application that works fine when the files are on a web host, but when I try to connect it to WAMPServer I get this error (which is on `json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)`)

I checked the configuration and everything but I don't know whats wrong so please help me

here is the code of AsyncTask

```
       @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {

/*            try {
                MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md5.update(password.getBytes(),0,password.length());
                password = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest()).toString(16);
                //System.out.println("Signature: "+signature);

            } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            //Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            //Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

here is the error

```
04-29 20:53:12.832  14648-14648/com.example.mysqltest E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40daa5f8 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40daa5f8 that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:352)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:373)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:321)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
        at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:541)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
        at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:103)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
        at com.example.mysqltest.Login.onClick(Login.java:77)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `when the files on a web host`. Which files?

Comment: `com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:103) `. What code is on line 103?

Comment: Status = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)

Comment: `(which is on json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS) ` Why do you think so? How do you see that in the logcat. I think you did not post enough of the logcat and that the real errors/exeptions are elsewhere.

Comment: Show full code please of onPreExecute. I think you have a NullPointerException because `json` == `null`.

Comment: OnPreExecute there's only code for show dialog

Comment: Please reread these comments as you told someting different before. For 103.

Comment: how to post the full code?

Comment: on line 103 there;s p.showDialog()

Comment: What is the data in `LOGIN_URL`